# Synchronous way to enter return key after run command in python?

Tags: python

I want run a command in shell. All of us know we can use the os.system(). But this command must need to be hit enter key to make this command complete.

Now I do it like follow:

```
 from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
 Popen(my_cmd.split(), stdin=PIPE).stdin.write('\n')
```

but it is asynchronous. I want to know, is there possible to use os.system() or some simple way to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.system()` is, while not deprecated, seen as superfluous by many people. Everything that can be done with it can be done using `subprocess` as well.

If you don't like the fact that your program and the other process run concurrently (I think that's what you mean with asynchronous), you could do

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
sp = Popen(my_cmd.split(), stdin=PIPE)
sp.stdin.write('\n')
sp.wait()
```

This last `.wait()` call makes the subprocess call "kind of synchronous".

Comment: Turns out [`os.system()` isn't marked as deprecated in the Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system), however `os.popen()` was deprecated in 2.6 and is marked as such.

Comment: @RobinJamesKerrison Thanks. I changed the wording in my answer now.